# Print all of output in Out-File command

Tags: powershell, printing

How to print all the information?

```
Get-AdUser -Properties name, displayname, description `
-filter {displayname -like '*(*' -or displayname -like '*_*' -or displayname -like '*/*' -or displayname -like '*\*'} `
| Select name, displayname, description `
| Out-File "C:\Temp\displayNameproperties.txt"
```

When it prints... part of the way through it stops due to console width limits. My excel file shows partial information when I need to see all the display name and description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're working with this data in Excel, you should be using `Export-CSV` instead of `out-file`. `Export-CSV` will preserve all of your data and make it usable by any software that can read the format.

```
Get-AdUser -Properties name, displayname, description `
-filter {displayname -like '*(*' -or displayname -like '*_*' -or displayname -like '*/*' -or displayname -like '*\*'} `
| Select-object -property name, displayname, description `
| Export-CSV "C:\Temp\displayNameproperties.csv" -notypeinformation
```

Comment: Tomorrow I will test out Export. Will keep you updated. thanks

Comment: Yes this worked. A little different print but does the job. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to output objects to a file, and that's going to get messy if you aren't at least kind of specific about how it's done. Try using the Export-CSV cmdlet, or format your data to readable strings and output that to a file.

Output to CSV:
Replace `Out-File` with `Export-CSV -NoType`

Format strings for output:
Change your Select to a ForEach that looks something like:

```
ForEach{"Name: {0}`tDisplay Name: {1}`tDescription: {2}" -f $_.name, $_.displayname, $_.description}
```

Then you can pipe that to Out-File like you have been. Or you can replace the Tab character (backtick followed by t) with a new line character (backtick followed by n).